# C++ How to fix dependency Issue between a typedef template and class

Tags: c++, templates

I am running into issues with placing order.

```
Class A
{
  private:
    B x;
};

typedef Vector<A> B;



template<class A>
class Vector{};
```

I was thinking of using a reference but my template doesn't like incomplete types.

Comment: This is not possible in general (as in, not in all cases). If `sizeof(Vector)` depends on `A` then there is a possibly infinite recursion. Note in particular the case `template<class A> class Vector { A a; };`. It is unclear what prevents you from putting the `Vector` definition before the `typedef Vector<A> B;` though, could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: @MaxLanghof I have a header file that includes the template vector so in theory the file that has my class A and my typdef B should come after the definition of the vector

Comment: Can you confirm whether [this](https://godbolt.org/z/VLhSDt) is a solution or not?

Comment: @MaxLanghof it is not

Comment: Then the problem is how your `Vector` class is defined. `std::vector` works in the same situation so it's not impossible to do what you want. If you show a piece of code that reproduces the problem (in a new question) we might be able to help you.

Comment: @MaxLanghof I figured out the answer. My ordering was off and my template was ok with taking a class reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this by reordering your declarations:

```
class A;

template<class T>
class Vector{};

typedef Vector<A> B;

class A
{
  private:
    B x;
};
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/IyLVWnOT7Lqthnu0)

Comment: The template declaration is in a different header file

Comment: That is unfortunate.  Can you change that?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't. This wasn't really an issue when I was using macros but now that Ive switched over to templates it will complain about incomplete types. Maybe I can put my typedef inside my class A?

Comment: You could try some experiments at Wandbox or similar, but the compiler still needs to see the definition of `Vector` before you use it,.

Comment: @BrogrammerDude Putting the typedef inside `A` [would not help](https://godbolt.org/z/byYuv7) because `A` is still an incomplete type until you reach the last `};`.